# Accessing a variable in vuejs or javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this javascript variable, I'm using vuejs.

when I try to access an array field to validate a form, the chrome dev tools returns an error.

```
var checkItems = {contact_email: "", contact_name: "", contact_phone: "", message: "", subject_id: null, …}
```

I try to access this way:

```
if(checkItems.contact_email)
      alert("email required");
```

This is the error:

```
 Property or method "contact_email" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option
```

If the form fields are empty, I want to detect individually which one is empty and send a custom error for each one, for example:
Name field is empty
The email field is empty

This is my vuejs code:

```
var locale = '{{ $lang }}'; //'es-ES',  

    var V_Alerts = new Vue({

        el : '#v-alerts',

        data : {

            types   : ['danger', 'warning', 'success', 'info'],

            alerts  : [
            ]
        },          

        methods : {

            add : function(type, content, opts)
            {                               
                this.alerts.push({
                    type : type,
                    content : content,
                    opts : opts
                });
            },

            addSuccess : function(content, opts){
                this.add('success',content, opts)
            }
        }
    });

    var new_ticket = new Vue({

        el      : '#create_ticket',

        data    : {
            uploading     : false,
            submitting    : false,
            subject_id    : null,
            message       : '',
            errors: [],
        },

        methods : {

            validation: function (params)
            {
                return {
                    contact_email : IsEmail(params.contact_email),
                    contact_name  : !!params.contact_name.trim(),                   
                    message       : !!params.message.trim(),
                    subject_id    : params.subject_id && !!params.subject_id.trim(),                    
                    captcha       : params.captcha !== 0
                }
            },

            isValid : function(params)
            {
                var validation = this.validation(params);

                return Object.keys(validation).every(function (key) {
                    return validation[key];
                });             
            },        

            restart : function()
            {
                this.uploading  = false;
                this.submitting = false;
                this.subject_id = null;                

                this.$refs.subjects.restart();
                this.$refs.uploads.restart();
                $('#message').text('');
                $('#order_number').val('');  

                $('#contact_email').val('');
                $('#contact_name').val('');
                $('#contact_phone').val('');
                $('#message').val(''); 
                grecaptcha.reset();     
            },            

            onSubjectSelect : function(subject_id){                
                this.subject_id = subject_id;                
            },

            _onSubjectsLoaded : function(subjects){                
                emitOnWidgetContentChanged();
            },


            createTicket : function(e)
            {                
                var params = {
                    contact_email : $('#contact_email').val(),
                    contact_name  : $('#contact_name').val(),
                    contact_phone : $('#contact_phone').val(),
                    message       : $('#message').val(),
                    subject_id    : this.subject_id,
                    message_files : this.$refs.uploads.completed_ids.join(','),
                    captcha       : grecaptcha.getResponse()                    
                };

                @if (Input::has('public_token'))
                    params.public_token = '{{ Input::get('public_token') }}';
                @endif

                if ($('#order_number').val() != '')
                    params.contact_orders = $('#order_number').val();

                if (!this.isValid(params))
                {
                    var checkItems = params;

                    if(checkItems.contact_email)
                        alert("email");

                    alert('{{ addslashes(trans('common.empty_or_error_input')) }}');                    
                    return;
                }                

                this.submitting   = true;
                // only ie11 need this manuall
                params._token = '{!! csrf_token() !!}'; 

                AjaxServices.post('createTicket', params, function(error, result)
                {                   
                    this.submitting = false;

                    if (error)
                    {
                        alert('{{  addslashes(trans('accounts/tickets.error_creating_ticket')) }}');                        
                        grecaptcha.reset();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert('#'+ result.ticket_id +' - {{  addslashes(trans('accounts/tickets.new_ticket_created_ok')) }} :)');
                        V_Alerts.addSuccess('#'+ result.ticket_id +' - {{  addslashes(trans('accounts/tickets.new_ticket_created_ok')) }}');                        
                        this.restart();                        
                        emitOnWidgetContentChanged();

                    }
                }.bind(this));                
            },

            onUploadComplete : function(ids){
                this.uploading = false;      
                emitOnWidgetContentChanged();
            },

            onUploadStarted : function(){
                this.uploading = true;
                setTimeout(emitOnWidgetContentChanged,1);
            },

            onItemDeleted : function(){

            },

            onFilesSelected : function(){               
            }                 
        }
    });

      function IsEmail(email) {
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    return regex.test(email);
  }     

    $(document).ready(function(){
        //new_ticket.restart();
    });
```

Comment: insert more full code pleasse

Comment: For this question it matters what your vue code looks like

Comment: @AliaksandrPitkevich I edit the main post

Comment: @Imre_G I edited the main post

Comment: Using jQuery and Vue interchangebly is missing the point in my opinion. Throw away jQuery and hop on the Vue boat completely. You won't be disappointed. You can do all this $.val() stuff by using v-model and v-bind.

Answer (score 1):

You are not utilizing Vue properly.  The error you are receiving stems from not defining your properties in the data object.  You cant just return them as you are in the `validation` method because Vue is looking for a data object called `contact_email`, or a method called `contact_email()` or even a computed property called `contact_email`.

```
  data    : {
          // define your properties here
          contact_email: '';
    },
  methods: {
     yourMethod: function(){
         //modify your properties here
         this.contact_email: IsEmail(params.contact_email)
       }
  }
```